# why wont my rca Voyager turn on?

Tags: connection-issues, power-on

It was working last night then twice I used it till it shut down (ran out of battery) completely and when I plugged it in, it came upon with the charging screen then this morning, it would t even turn on. I e tried pushing power while it's plugged in, not plugged in, pushing reset button and pushing volume up and power at same time and since this morning, it won't even show the charging screen, let alone the start screen